# Notation for defining a homomorphism

Tags: galois-theory

I am currently reading about extensions generated by an algebraic element, and the book gives the following definition:

Let $L$ be an extension of a field $K$, and let $a\in L$ be algebraic over $K$. Let $K[a]$ denote the smallest subring containing $K$ and $a$, i.e. the image of the homomorphism $f: K[X] \to L$ defined by $f(X)=a$.

I'm not sure what is meant by the notation $f(X)=a$, given that the elements of $K[X]$ are polynomials with coefficients in $K$, can someone please elaborate on the exact map being defined here?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question... What is bothering you in a map that sends $X$ to $a$?

Comment: I guess my question is that although the map is defined from $K[X]$ to $L$, is this just saying to evaluate each polynomial at $a$?

Comment: yes.. It is just evaluation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author means that the homomorphism $f$ is entirely determined by the value of $X$ under $f$ (i.e. the value $f(X)=a \in L$). Presumably $f$ is assumed to be a $K$-algebra homomorphism. For any polynomial $p(X) = b_n X^n +\ldots +b_0 \in K[X]$, using the properties of $K$-algebra homomorphisms, it follows that $$f(p(X)) = b_n a^n + b_{n-1}a^{n-1}+\ldots b_0 \in L$$ That $f$ is entirely determined by the point $f(X)$ and that this choice is unrestricted is what we mean when we say that $K[X]$ is the free $K$-algebra on one generator.

Comment: So I guess my confusion came from wondering why you wouldn't just write that the map $f$ sends $p(x) \mapsto p(a)$?

Comment: I just don't see the necessity of the notation used.

Comment: You certainly could, and the statement would be the same. It is more useful to use the given notation from the perspective of category theory though, since $K[X]$ has the universal property of being free as I mentioned.